# iOS can't get person's image

Tags: ios, addressbook

I have two tableViewControllers. The first one has a list of contacts. The another one shows detailed person's information.

A chunk of code of first tableViewController

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
NSArray *allPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source,kABPersonSortByFirstName);
for ( int i = 0; i < [allPeople count]; i++ )
{
    ...
    contactClass = [[ContactClass alloc] initWithName:name surName:surName manID:[allPeople objectAtIndex:i]];
    ...
}
```

A chunck of code of second tableViewController

```
ABRecordRef person = (__bridge  ABRecordRef)contactClass.manID;
BOOL isHasImage = ABPersonHasImageData(person);
```

Variable isHasImage is always false, even if contact has an avatar. I even checked this on the first tableViewController and if person has an avatar, then it returns true and image.

Does anyone knows why I can't get contacts image?

p.s. `contactClass.manID` is type of `id`. It has a correct adress, because `ABMultiValueRef multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)contactClass.manID, kABPersonPhoneProperty);` returns correct value in the second tableViewController

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I may be too late for a solution for you, but maybe this will help others that are stuck with the same problem. 
Looks like `ABPersonHasImageData()` and `ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat()` don't work as expected on `ABRecordRef` copies (e.g. an `ABContactRef` from an array obtained using `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople()`), at leas on iOS 5.x. You may workaround it like this:

```
- (UIImage*)imageForContact: (ABRecordRef)contactRef {
    UIImage *img = nil;

    // can't get image from a ABRecordRef copy
    ABRecordID contactID = ABRecordGetRecordID(contactRef);
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    ABRecordRef origContactRef = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, contactID);

    if (ABPersonHasImageData(origContactRef)) {
        NSData *imgData = (NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(origContactRef, kABPersonImageFormatOriginalSize);
        img = [UIImage imageWithData: imgData]; 

        [imgData release];
    }

    CFRelease(addressBook);

    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any further update on this ?

I have received complaints for some user not able to see thumbnail for a few contacts. Mostly it works fine, Is there any special case in which thumbnails aren't returned.

I am using the following piece of code:

```
 - (instancetype)initWithABContact:(ABRecordRef)contact {
          NSData *iThumbnailData = nil;
          if (ABPersonHasImageData(contact)) {
            iThumbnailData =
            CFBridgingRelease(ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(contact, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail));
          }
    }
```